# In Napili template, can I use default login for Internal Pages?

Tags: community, napili

Can I use the default login to give access to users for going to internal pages in Salesforce Napili Community? and have the Community home page as public?

I want to access an internal community page after asking for login from the user. Since I can't use custom login page( as pwd can't be retrieved for the user by querying), I want to use the default login of Napili community. What should I target

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make the page public without requesting login access, once you are in the builder, access the settings component:
[image]

as per the other pages, it is important you understand the following:

> Page Access Your community-wide access level is set to Public.
>   However, access to this object page depends on your Salesforce
>   security settings.

Additionally, if you want to narrow down who can access what based on profiles, you can either set page variations and or target an audience through the page settings:

[image]